# getting records from 2 tables

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables called bookings and guest2 . So I want to show data from both tables where checkindate is today. I have written like this. But it shows all records.

```
 <?php 
    echo $today=date("j-n-Y"); 

        include("connect.php");

        $SQL="SELECT bookings.bookingid, guest2.fname, guest2.lname
                FROM bookings
                LEFT JOIN guest2
                ON bookings.guestid=guest2.guestid
                AND bookings.checkindate = '$today'
                ORDER BY bookings.bookingid ";

        $run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL2 error");

        while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run))
                    {

                    echo "booking ID".$rec['bookingid']."";
                    echo "Guest Name".$rec['fname']."";
                    echo " ".$rec['lname']."";


                    }

?>
```

[booking table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5HIx.jpg)
[guest2 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REmau.jpg)

Any idea?

Comment: No dear ..it was a silly mistake  $today=date("j-n-Y");  This must be change to $today=date("Y-n-j"); according to the my table... Now it works.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `left join`, so all the records in the first able a returned.  Move the condition on the first table to a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT b.bookingid, g.fname, g.lname
FROM bookings b LEFT JOIN
     guest2 g
     ON b.guestid = g.guestid
WHERE b.checkindate = '$today'
ORDER BY b.bookingid;
```

Alternatively, the `LEFT JOIN` is probably unnecessary -- assuming that all bookings have valid guests.  If so, you can just change the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` in your original query.

Comment: No dear ..it was a silly mistake  $today=date("j-n-Y");  This must be change to $today=date("Y-n-j"); according to the my table... Now it works.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$SQL="SELECT bookings.bookingid, guest2.fname, guest2.lname
        FROM bookings
        INNER JOIN guest2
        ON bookings.guestid=guest2.guestid
        where bookings.checkindate = '$today'
        ORDER BY bookings.bookingid ";
```

1) Use inner join 
2) add where condition